# Explicit intent and action performed

Tags: android, android-intent

I am wondering how does the following code works (it starts an activity). I don't get how does the system figure out what is the action that should be preformed. No action is specified for the Intent. I would have expected a set_action.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
startActivity(i);
```

I am wondering how is it possible to have an Intent which action is not explicitely specified considering what I read in the documentation:

> The primary pieces of information in an intent are:
>
> - action -- The general action to be performed, such as ACTION_VIEW, ACTION_EDIT, ACTION_MAIN, etc.
> - data -- The data to operate on, such as a person record in the contacts database, expressed as a Uri.

I hope it make sense. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types of intents in Android, implicit intents and explicit intents.

**1) Implicit intent**

You set an Action, Category and data type and let Android find an activity that fits the specified characteristics (has an intent filter with the specified Action, Category and Data Type).

**2) Explicit intent**

As the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters#ExampleExplicit) says:

> An explicit intent is one that you use to launch a specific app
>   component, such as a particular activity or service in your app. To
>   create an explicit intent, define the component name for the Intent
>   object—all other intent properties are optional.

You tell which activity/service to open explicitly. So the system doesn't need to figure out which one to open, you're already telling it to open a specific Activity/Service.

The one you read in the docs is an implicit intent, this is the explicit one:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but from what I understand and intent should have an action to be performed. In the implicit intent the action is explicit but for the explicit intent it is not. How does the system figure out the action to be performed when using the Intent constructor you specified?

Comment: Not all intents should specify an action, in the docs (specified above) you'll see that in the case of explicit intent the action/category and data are optionals :)

Comment: In the page where you found about intent action there's this bit about explicit intents."Often these will not include any other information, simply being a way for an application to launch various internal activities it has as the user interacts with the application."

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple constructor functions for Intent class.
If checking the source code for public Intent(Context packageContext, Class cls), the following info is mentioned:

> Create an intent for a specific component.  All other fields (action, data,
>        * type, class) are null, though they can be modified later with explicit
>        * calls.  This provides a convenient way to create an intent that is
>        * intended to execute a hard-coded class name, rather than relying on the
>        * system to find an appropriate class for you;